# ASINetworkQueue without setting DownloadDestinationPath

Tags: asihttprequest, ios5.1, imagedownload

I want to fetch multiple images from the server for which I wish to use the `ASINetworkQueue`. I was wondering if setting the downloadDestinationPath using `setDownloadDestinationPath:path` for `ASIHTTPRequest` object is necessary. Is there a way to use `ASINetworkQueue` without setting the DownloadDestinationPath? If so, how to go about it? Also what happens to the images once they are downloaded in the Documents directory. I do not wish to pile up all the images as my project involves extensive use of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `tag` property of the ASIHTTPRequest object to set different tags for each of my request before adding them to the ASINetworkQueue object.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request;
    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageURLDictionary objectForKey:@"test1"]]];
    request.tag=1;
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageURLDictionary objectForKey:@"test2"]]];
    request.tag=2;
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];

    request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageURLDictionary objectForKey:@"test3"]]];
    request.tag=3;
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
```

And on success and failure handled them in the delegate method.

```
- (void)imageFetchComplete:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
if (request.tag==1) {
    _image1.image=[UIImage imageWithData:request.responseData];
}
if (request.tag==2) {
    _image2.image=[UIImage imageWithData:request.responseData];
}
if (request.tag==3) {
    _image3.image=[UIImage imageWithData:request.responseData];
}
}
```